# Move specific object through another specific object while both have colliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a object `Enemy` and another one `Wall`

Enemy has a `CapsuleCollider` and Wall has a `BoxCollider`

The Wall prevents the player from moving through it. But i want that the Enemy can move through the wall.

What i tried was setting up an `array` with all the walls that i want the Enemy to pass and than ignore the collision on the enemy object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < wand.Length; i++)
{            
    Physics.IgnoreCollision(wand[i].GetComponent<Collider>(), GetComponent<Collider>());
}
```

But they still get blocked from the wall, when they try to move through it.

I can't set the enemy's collider to Trigger, because i need the collision to prevent them from running through other objects.

i also tried this one from that site:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/ignore-collisions-by-tag-solved.60387/

```
function OnCollisionEnter (collision : Collision) {

    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Wall") {
    Physics.IgnoreCollision(collision.collider, collider);
        }

}
```

But it doens't work either.

Someone got any idea how to solve this?

Comment: put the walls in the layer Walls, and the enemies in the layer Enemies, then go to physics options and set that those 2 layers don't collide.

Comment: @Lestat, make it a proper answer, pls

Comment: Done @RodrigoRodrigues

Comment: Thank you. _answer as comment_ has been a hard-to-solve problem in SO. (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat )

Answer (score 3):

Put them in different Layers and then set them so they don't collide with each other.

- 1. Add the walls to the "Walls" Layer.
- 2. Add the enemies to the "Enemies" Layer.
- 3. Go to Edit->Project Settings->Physics. And deactivate the collisions between those 2 Layers.

Comment: While this should work I think OP want's to do this during run-time to be able enable/disable collision with some certain object. This is what I feel about this. I may be wrong

Comment: @Programmer i don't need to change it during run-time, so this would be enough, but unfortunately, they still can't get through the wall.

Comment: @AlpakaJoe If you don't need the change it during tun-time then this answer is what you're looking for and **should** work. 1.Add EDIT to your question and provide a screenshot of what you did in the Physics settings. 2.Also select the objects you want to make go through another and take screenshot of the "Inspector" tab of them and post them. With these two, we can troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: how are you mobving the enemies? if you're using navmesh than the enemies will indeed be stopped by the walls because the navmesh is built like that, so buikld the navmesh without the walls (disable them when baking) and thats it